# Нестандартные рамки у блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, css3

[image: как сделать такую рамку]

как сделать такую рамку. при наведении на блок уголки должны съезжаться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/rm569err/

html:

```
<div class="my_div"></div>
```

css:

```
.my_div {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
.my_div:before {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 270px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  content: " ";
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.my_div:after {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  content: " ";
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.my_div:hover:before {
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.my_div:hover:after {
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Так же можно через [svg](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css/)

Comment: @Olegatro, подозреваю, что вариантов решения даже не два) просто этот мне показался самым очевидным и svg, признаться честно, не очень люблю использовать